# Chrome opening CSV file instead of save it

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a PHP application that generates a CSV file and redirect the user to a static page linking to the file, just the example below :

https://www.example.com/public_html/static/temp/myfile.csv

Problem is, Chrome is opening the file instead of saving it. I need Chrome to save this file, as it would do with any other file like a zip or mp3, for instance.

Here is what I tried :

```
header('location:https://www.example.com/public_html/static/temp/myfile.csv');    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.csv');
```

But no luck, Chrome keeps showing the myfile.csv contents instead of downloading it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: the `Content-Disposition` has no meaning here in this request processing, it should be in the response headers of the next request to  `/public_html/static/temp/myfile.csv` make sure that the second request has `'Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the response headers

Comment: This is wrong both in convention and logic: HTTP headers should have the proper casing and a space after the colon. And calling `https://domain/file.csv` will nowhere execute your PHP code. On top: redirecting an HTTP request (thru `Location:`) lets the client request the new URI, not pass the server the target's content. Solution: serve a PHP file which outputs your CSV.

Comment: @AmigoJack When i redirect to the CSV file, the PHP code is already executed and the file ready to be downloaded

Comment: @Accountantم I didn't really catch the idea, can you explain more ?

Comment: @delphirules if the request  to `/public_html/static/temp/myfile.csv` has the `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the response headers , Chrome will download the file instead of opening it, make sure the response has this header from chrome network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: @Accountantم But i'm already sending this header along with the location one ?

Comment: @delphirules No, this is a different request. **First** request is to your PHP file which generates the csv file, save it on disk and redirects the browser to `/myfile.csv`. **Second** request is to `/myfile.csv` and must has the `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the response headers

Comment: @Accountantم In the example above when i redirect to the CSV file, it's already generated by a previous PHP script. I just want to redirect the user to the CSV file and force it to be downloaded, not show on the browser

Comment: @delphirules **1-** This code snippet in the question is in the PHP file that generates the csv file, right ?  **2-** What is the URL of the PHP file that generates the csv file, and what is the URL to the csv static file ?

Comment: @Accountantم The url that generates the CSV is like 'https://www.example.com/controller/report.php'. Inside this script i generate the CSV file and redirect to the CSV using the code i provided in the question.

Comment: @delphirules Ok this plan will make the browser do **2 request**, first one is to `report.php` file which will generates the csv file and save it on disk and redirect the browser to the static file, second request is to the static file at `myfile.csv`, you need `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the response of the **second** request to `myfile.csv` not the first one to `report.php`. open the networks tab and see this happening in action and make sure that the second request has `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the response.

Comment: @Accountantم Somehow  the browser is not receiving the Content-Disposition header : (

Comment: @delphirules OK can you please do these 3 tests , **1-** will chrome open [this csv file](http://insight.dev.schoolwires.com/HelpAssets/C2Assets/C2Files/C2ImportCalEventSample.csv) or download it ? **2-** do chrome and Firefox having the same behavior ? or it is just Chrome ? **3-** check the `Content-Type` header of the response of the second request in your application , what is it  ?

Answer (score 1):

Your argumentation in the comments has one never-ending misunderstanding: the `Location` header instructs any client to perform a new request to the given URI. With that the current request is over. Headers from the current request (i.e. `Content-Disposition`) aren't magically carried over to the next request.

In other words: your "static page linking to the file, just the example below" must send your wanted header.

Ultimately I'm sure it's not a Chrome problem either, but affects all internet browsers, as they easily detect the CSV data as text, hence being able to render/display that data instead of only being able to save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

With html5 you can set the "download" attr in an element.

Download it!
Source : http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

Comment: Thanks but i don't really have an element that links to the CSV file ; the user click on a button that will trigger a PHP script and then this script generates the CSV file and redirect

Comment: More official link: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score -1):

After struggling with this issue for some days, the only real solution i got is to ZIP the file and then redirecting to the ZIP file instead of the CSV. By doing this, Chrome will download the ZIP file instead of opening it :

```
header('location:https://www.example.com/public_html/static/temp/myfile.csv.zip');
```

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution. And you write your header instruction wrong.